# How and why should I use the 'In-App Purchase Content' template within Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, xcode-template

I'm wanting to develop an application that will have in-app purchasing ability for non-consumable features/upgrades.  After reading through a few documents today, this looks pretty easy.

While looking through the available Xcode iOS templates, I saw that there is a template called "In-App Purchase Content".

I've tried to google this thing but I can't find the point of the template, nor how to implement it.

**What is the templates purpose and how can I use this template to my advantage?**

Comment: I wwanted to bump this question.  I've received an answer but since it doesn't include any references, I'm still a bit confused.  Can someone provide a bit of clarity?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In-App Purchasing Resources**

I know this is an old question but I am providing an answer because the information is still relevant and still difficult to locate. The template does allow one to submit content that will be stored on the Apple app store. There is no Apple documentation on it's use but Techotopia has a nice [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_6_In-App_Purchases) for using this template. Apple has a technical note on adding in-app [purchases](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578). The in-app programming guide is also [available](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267).

Comment: Thank you Tommie.  Believe it or not, I've been hoping someone would answer this.

Comment: @RLH - Thanks for asking the question, it just so happens I needed to find the answer as well. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have Apple host your In-app purchase content for you. The template uses a new target for In App Purchase content which you can use to validate/submit said content to the store via the Organizer.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you happen to have a reference for more specific details?

Comment: This my primary source for instructions on using the Built-In Xcode method of submitting in-app purchases.  I can verify that this works, as I have tried it as of 10/29/13.  http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios_6/changes_to_storekit/